# Pipe invert and obvert: Why is it called invert?

Tags: meaning, terminology

In [civil engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14640/pipe-invert-and-obvert-why-is-it-called-invert), the words **invert** and **obvert** are used in the context of pipe elevations. I gather that **invert** means: *interior bottom elevation of pipe*, and **obvert** means: *interior top elevation of pipe*.

[image: This is a diagram of a pipe with arrows labeling the various parts. The crown is the outer top, the obvert is the inner top, and the invert is the inner-bottom. It also illustrates the external and internal diameters, with Size = Nominal internal Diameter(DD) near the upper right corner, with an arrow pointing to the inner diameter]

However, using the word **invert** in this context seems strange to me. To me, none of these definitions fit:

> **Invert** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invert))
>
> 1. **a**: to reverse in position, order, or relationship
>      **b:** to subject to inversion
> 2. **a**: to turn inside out or upside down
>      **b**: to turn inward
> 3. **a:** to find the mathematical reciprocal of 
>      **b:** to divide using fractions, invert the divisor and multiply

What does the word **invert** have to do with pipes? 
What has been inverted?

Comment: Ultimately, it's jargon.

Comment: Nothing wrong with jargon: we even have a tag for it. By all means edit it in if that tag is appropriate here. I'm not sure it is (but then I trained as an engineer, so whether it's jargon or not may be difficult to determine).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I just tried, but it didn't take effect. It appears to already be categorized as a [tag synonym](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology/synonyms) of [tag:terminology], which the question already had.

Comment: This online dictionary actually has the best explanation: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ob- [...]but now used also, with the sense of “reversely,” “inversely,” to form Neo-Latin and English scientific terms: object; obligate; oblanceolate. If you take invert and obvert together, the obvert is the reverse of the invert.

Comment: The inverted arch thing would make even more sense to me if, historically, pipes were just trenches/inverted arches/channels, and not tubular.

Comment: @Tonepoet Thanks to your input on my answer, it's earned the 'nice answer' badge. Well done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [*The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia*](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/invert) s.v. [Invert](http://www.finedictionary.com/invert.html): In architecture, an inverted arch; specifically, the floor of the lock-chamber of a canal, which is usually in the form of an inverted arch, or the bottom of a sewer.
>
> > The bottom of the sewer is called the invert from a general resemblance in construction to an "inverted" arch. *Mayhew, London Labour and London Poor*, II 445.

[image: A list of dictionary definitions from the Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia, with the quoted entry in a red box.]

Answer (score 8):

See the noun part of **invert** at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invert)

> An arch constructed in an upside-down position to provide lateral support, e.g. in a tunnel.

[image: invert]

So you see, the bottom concave part is like an upside down arch, which is in discussion here.